# cakephp login form action url error in contactform Plugin

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I'm new to cakePHP and I face an error with form helper in plugin on Xampp localhost. Firstly the contact form I use is from https://github.com/patrickhafner/ContactForm-CakePHP-2

The form action is correct when surfing the url localhost/mysite/post

```
form action="/job/users/login"
```

However when surfing the url in localhost/job/contact which use the ContactForm plugin, showing

```
form action="/job/contact/users/login"
```

the sign in form code is below

```
echo $this->BootstrapForm->create('User', array('action' => '/login','class'=>'form-signin'));
echo $this->BootstrapForm->input('email');
echo $this->BootstrapForm->input('password');
echo $this->BootstrapForm->submit('Sign In');
echo $this->BootstrapForm->end();
```

I've tried things such as `Configure::write('App.base','/');` however it result in ruining my whole pages. Any idea what I've done wrong or what I've missed out in the manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the form action like this.

```
<?php 
   echo $this->BootstrapForm->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin' => false),'class'=>'form-signin'));

?>
```

For more info follow the [url.](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#options-url)

Comment: the above code still outputting the same error for me, however using another turnaround `echo $this->BootstrapForm->create('User', array('url' => '/users/login','class'=>'form-signin'));` does solve the problem

Comment: I think, you should try at once because both of the code will generate the same output follow the [URL](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#options-url) for more details.

Comment: I've tried many time however it's not generate the same output.

Comment: Are you using admin routing? if yes then you have to specify the `'admin' => false` with form url option.

Comment: nope, and have tried `'admin' => false` in url option and has failed.
using `CakePlugin::load('Contactform', array('routes' => true));`

Comment: then add `'plugin' => false`.

Comment: now it's correct! complete working code is `echo $this->BootstrapForm->create('User', array('url' => array('action' => '/login','plugin' => false),'class'=>'form-signin'));`